# How do I find the perimeter of objects in a binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently using the `bwperim` function like so:

```
BW2 = bwperim(BW);
```

`BW` is an input binary image and `BW2` is another binary image that shows the perimeter of all distinct binary objects in `BW`.  However, I'm not quite sure how `bwperim` works and so I'd like to implement an algorithm that performs what `bwperim` does without using the function itself.

As such, how does `bwperim` find the perimeter of objects in a binary image?  Is there a known algorithm that does this?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `bwperim`?  This simply finds the perimeter of all objects in a binary image.  The simplest way to do this is to erode the image with a 3 x 3 structuring element and subtract this result with the original binary image.

Comment: @rayryeng can u please show me with a coding example??

Comment: Are you allowed to use `imerode`?

Comment: @rayryeng yes we can make use of imerode.

Comment: No problem :) I figured I'd restructure it slightly so that it would be better for future readers. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest techniques to find the perimeter of binary objects in images is to perform [morphological erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) using a very small structuring element.... usually a 3 x 3 square.  Once you find the erosion, you simply perform an image subtraction with the original image and the eroded result.

When performing morphological erosion, the areas of the objects are decreased slightly with their perimeters also reduced.  By using a 3 x 3 square structuring element, you are decreasing the perimeter of border pixels by 1 pixel and so subtracting this result with the original will give you the perimeter of the objects.

Given that your binary image is stored in `BW`, you would simply do this:

```
se = strel('square', 3);
BWerode = imerode(BW, se);
BWper = logical(abs(imsubtract(BWerode, BW)));
```

Take note that when we subtract, there may be a case of **negative** differences.  We don't want that, so we take the `abs`, then cast back to `logical` (a.k.a. true/false).  `BWper` contains the image that finds the perimeter of all of our objects.  Be advised that if you have any objects that are **smaller** than a 3 x 3 square, then you won't get any perimeter results... but I'm assuming you wouldn't want to find the perimeter of such small objects in any case.

Here's an example image that I have that consists of a bunch of squares:

[image]

We can read this in to MATLAB like so, and it's already binary:

```
BW = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk0o0.png');
```

Running the above perimeter finding code, this is the image we get:

[image]

If you compare this with `bwperim`, you'll see that we get more or less the same results.