# Plot a 2D binary matrix as a line in matplotlib using plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D matrix containing zeros and ones. The ones define a shape from which I want to plot its contour/edge on a matplotlib figure. The initial 2D binary matrix:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878844/how-do-i-find-the-perimeter-of-objects-in-a-binary-image) the method to get the corresponding 2D binary matrix of the edge of the shape:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Using plt.imshow, I get the following result:
[image]

**How would you do to plot the ones in this matrix as a dotted line in a matplotlib figure using plt.plot() ?** I would like to get this result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more complex geometries than a rectangle you can use the [ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) from [scipy.spatial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html):

```python
#starting with the original data
data = [
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

#convert the data array into x-y coordinates
#assume (0,0) is the lower left corner of the array
def array_to_coords(data):
    for y, line in enumerate(reversed(data)):
        for x, point in enumerate(line):
            if point == 1:
                yield(x, y)

points = list(array_to_coords(data))

#plot the points, skip this if you only need the dotted line
x,y = zip(*points)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,5)

#plot the convex hull
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
hull = ConvexHull(points)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(hull.points[simplex,0], hull.points[simplex,1], 'ro-')
```

[image]

A more complex situation:

```python
data = [
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

[image: complexer situation]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the same, but maybe it can give you a start.  You can see what I did.  I extracted the x,y locations of the 1 values, then plotted x against y in a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
array = np.array(
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

coords = np.argwhere(array==1)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.scatter(coords[:,1],coords[:,0])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

**Followup**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
array = np.array(
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

coords = np.argwhere(array==1)
xmin = np.min(coords[:,1])
xmax = np.max(coords[:,1])
ymin = np.min(coords[:,0])
ymax = np.max(coords[:,0])
x = [xmin,xmin,xmax,xmax,xmin]
y = [ymin,ymax,ymax,ymin,ymin]

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.plot(x, y, '--')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Second answer]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried with scatter which is not what I'm looking for, that's why I clarified in my post that I want to use the plot method to get a proper line, not indépendant points !

Comment: If you know it's always going to be a rectangle, then it doesn't take much imagination to derive the corners from what I've done there.  I'll modify the answer.